# Programmatically submit a form

Tags: .net, forms

I've seen a tons of sample to how to programmatically submit a form (in .NET) but none of them has the specific requirements I need.

The case I'm working on has a query string (http://.../index=?p=update), some hidden fields and a upload file.

Does anyone has managed to submit this kind of form with a webrequest?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Fabian

Comment: If you haven't already you could use a tool like Fiddler (www.fiddlertool.com) to help you examine the GET and POST methods in real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/multipart_request_C_.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Examine the form method. If it's GET, then you'll need to send all data in the URL. This means you simply append `&field1=value1&field2=value2...` etc. (field1, field2 being the id or name of the field).

It is more likely POST. You'll have to set the request method to post ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx)). However, this does not mention the interesting part: what should I write into the request stream? This is (surprisingly) the same you would apply to the URL when GET method was used:

```
string requestString = String.Format("field1={0}&field2={1}", value1, value2);
```

And write this string into the request stream. That is all, this should work. (you can also mix the two, e.g. can use the p=update paramter in the URL, while POSTing data)